# Using set on a pandas series with no duplicate values returns a smaller object

Tags: python, pandas, set

I have a pandas series with unique values but somehow when using `set` (or `pd.unique()` for that matter) returns a smaller object.

```
In [255]: titles.shape
Out[255]: (77767,)

In [256]: len(set(titles))
Out[256]: 77750

In [257]: titles.nunique()
Out[257]: 77750
```

While examining further I have found out that what `set` sees as duplicates share some resemblance with each other, but they aren't actual duplicates.

```
In [254]: titles[titles.duplicated()]
Out[254]: 
927892                            Sham (film)
945686                     Shalom in the Home
947578                            Sham (play)
4380452                Blind Spot (1958 film)
4390747                Blind Spot (1932 film)
4403857                     Blind Rage (film)
4406443                  Blind Witness (film)
4421728                          Blind Terror
4424566                Blind Spot (1947 film)
4435819                           Blind Wives
4441354                           Blind Youth
4452296                Blind Side (1993 film)
4629350                  Ports of Call (film)
5562561                 Great Day (1945 film)
5586514              Great Day in the Morning
5634649    Great Continental Railway Journeys
5640835           Great Day (unfinished film)
Name: Title, dtype: object
```

What exactly triggers this strange issue? Title entries with the same first word are considered duplicates by `set`. And what is stranger is, I am using the Wikipedia dataset to extract these movie titles, so there must be more entries that have the same first word. But here we see only these 17 titles.

```
In [265]: title_list = list(titles)

In [266]: len(title_list)
Out[266]: 77767

In [267]: title_list = [i.split()[0] for i in title_list]

In [268]: len(set(title_list))
Out[268]: 17696
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT2: 
Removed the link to the data, since the question was answered successfully.

Comment: Can you provide us titles data?

Comment: How do you mean provide?

Comment: Put it somewhere on the web.

Comment: Just updated with a link to the data.

Comment: what you should show here is `titles[titles.duplicated(keep=False)]`.  That will show both occurrences of duplicates instead of just one or the other.  And you don't need to give us the whole dataset, just the parts that are being treated as duplicates

Comment: Yes. As you can see the resemblance of the elements that I show above is so uncanny that it made me think that there was something else going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make simple example:

```
check = pd.Series([1,2,2,3,4,2])
check[check.duplicated()]
#2 2
#5 2
dtype: int64
```

So, this shows duplicates w/o the first instance.

Correct approach would be:

```
check[check.isin(check[check.duplicated()])]
#1 2
#2 2
#5 2
```

Comment: Ah, I thought mistakenly that my series had no duplicates in it. Thanks for the correction.